# Github Pages only displays readme.md file of Anguar project

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-cli, github-pages

I've read both of the other topics on this site pertaining to this same issue, but nothing is resolving it and it's becoming so frustrating as I REALLY want to build a portfolio.

I have tried to host several of my Angular apps via Github Pages, and no matter what I do, it will only display the readme.md file or a 404 Error page. I've tried updating my version of the CLI, changing the angular.json to having a different outputPath (just the dist folder), using different command line prompts to refer to the directory as the "dist" folder, deleting the readme file (!!!), making a 404 error html page with the code from my index.html page -- basically every single solution I could find on the internet. My page serves locally just fine.

I also have tried to deploy them via Firebase and Heroku and both of them just give me generic error pages too. I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I build it, enable ghpages, and do an ngh command. It gives me no errors whatsoever in the console.

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions here: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#deploy-to-github-pages

Comment: So the thing is, when you build an angular app, it builds it and places all the files in the dist folder. The only things you require are the contents of the dist folder and nothing else. If I were to host it, I'd use the dist folder contents as the root folder.

Comment: @Pace -- yes I've done it this way as well. This way does not show me the readme file, but rather just a blank white page with no content. In inspecting the console of the page it basically says it's unable to load any of my content. However, my page serves just fine locally with no errors

Comment: @Dylan When you refer to the "root" folder, do you mean the directory? (assuming that's what dir stands for). I have been doing the command ngh --dir=dist for that reason

Answer (score 0):

First go to your repository setting and search for the tab `GitHub Pages`.

There is a Source section in whitch you have to selecte the `master brnch / docs folder`(see img bellow).

[image]

Now crate a directory named `docs` in your root directory.

Then run the command `ng build --prod`, after the command finished you must copy the content of your `dist/` directory into the `docs/` folder.

Optionaly you can modify you `angular.json` to write your build output into the `docs/` folder. 
Simply change the output path to `"outputPath": "docs/"`.